# How to create pagination using jquery from all divs with the same class?

Tags: jquery

I have an object **results** with 100 records(rows) outputed on my page.

But it's too much and I want to choped the results in e.g. 5 pages for 20 rows (results)

How can I create a page with pagination using only jquery or some simple jquery plugin?

E.g. I want to grab everything with a class `cars-result` and make 5 pages for 20 results.

```
<div id="main">

    <div class="cars-result">
          <h3>Result 1</h3>
          <div>Category: Dog</div>
          <p>dfasdf asdf asf asdf asdf asfd </p>
    </div>

    <div class="cars-result">
          <h3>Result 2</h3>
          <div>Category: Cat</div>
          <p>dfasdf asdf asf asdf asdf asfd </p>
    </div>

    <div class="cars-result">
          <h3>Result 3</h3>
          <div>Category: Dog</div>
          <p>dfasdf asdf asf asdf asdf asfd </p>
    </div>

    <div class="cars-result">
          <h3>Result 4/h3>
          <div>Category: Dog</div>
          <p>dfasdf asdf asf asdf asdf asfd </p>
    </div>

    ...


</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not a proper tool for creating pagination, it should be done on the server-side.

Comment: @undefined I know but I have to do this using javascript. Like creating tabs but pagination.

Comment: @undefined [citation needed]

Answer (score 3):

I hope something like this works out for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="paging"></div>
```

The first div is a container for the entries of a page.
The second div contains the links needed for paging through the pages.

jQuery:

```
 var results = [], // contains your rows
    page = 1, // current page
    pagesize = 20; // items per page

// load objects and generate entries and paging links
$(document).ready(function() {
    // objects = GetObjects();
    loadPage();
    generatePagingLinks();
}) 

// changing page when user clicks on a paging link
$("#paging").on("click", "a", function() {
    page = $(this).text();
    loadPage();
});

// function for generating paging links
function generatePagingLinks() {
    var links = Math.ceil(results.length / pagesize); // calculate number of links

    $("#paging").children("a").remove(); // Remove existing paging links

    // generate new paging links
    for (var i = 0; i < links; i++)
        $("<a>").attr("href", "#").text(i + 1).appendTo("#paging");
}

// function for loading the entries of a single page
function loadPage() {
    // Remove existing entries
    $("#main").children(".cars-result").remove();

    // Iterate through objects and generate new entries
    for (var i = pagesize * page - 1; i < pagesize * page; i++) {
        if (!objects[i])
            break;

        var div = $("<div>").addClass("cars-result");
        $("<h3>").text(results[i].Head).appendTo(div);
        $("<div>").text(results[i].Category).appendTo(div);
        $("<p>").text(results[i].Text).appendTo(div);

        $(div).appendTo('#main');
    }
}
```

This is just very simple, but I hope it helps you. The logic should be fairly easy to understand.
Unfortunately I don't have time to test it, but feel free to ask if something is not clear, or if somethings needs changes to suit your needs.